# How to rotate an object to make it face a certain direction?

Tags: three.js

If I know what direction an object is facing for example (0, 0, 1). What is the easiest way to rotate the object to face a direction vector of (1, 1, 1)?

Edit:

I've tried this, but something is wrong with this logic:

```
var newDir = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1);

var objectDir= new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1); 
objectDir.applyQuaternion(object.quaternion); // rotate this vector to object's facing direction

var pos = new THREE.Vector3();
pos.addVectors(newDir, object.position);

var axis = objectDir.cross(newDir).normalize();
var angle = objectDir.angleTo(pos);
object.rotateOnAxis(axis, angle);
```

Comment: Take a look at the methods on Object3d. Something like `lookAt` or `rotateOnAxis` is possibly what you want.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I tried to use rotateOnAxsis now, edited my post. But it doesn't look in the correct direction. Do you see any flaw in the code?

Comment: On the `dev67` branch there is a new function `Quaternion.setFromUnitVectors()`: `var vfrom = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 ); var vto =  new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1 ).normalize(); object.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors( vfrom, vto );` If object "up-ness" matters to you, then use `object.lookAt()`, which is probably the easiest anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it with lookAt:

```
var newDir = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1);
var pos = new THREE.Vector3();
pos.addVectors(newDir, object.position);
object.lookAt(pos);
```